# 400 bad request - jquery WCF ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I know this question has been posted multiple times before but even looking into the solution of those questions didnot work. So, finally i had to post the question:-

This is my ajax script

```
 function CallWebservice()
 {
    var textboxvalue = $('#TextBox1').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhos/Service1.svc/GetData",
            type: "POST",
            data: '{"value": "' + textboxvalue + '"}',
            dataType: "json",
            processdata: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (res) { 
            alert(res);
             },
        });
   }
```

The following is the service Interface code:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
[ServiceContract]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData(string value);

    [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

    // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }
 }
```

Service code

```
   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=        AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return (value == "Bose") ? "true" : "false";
    }
}
```

web.config

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="ApplicationServices"
     connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated      Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
 </authentication>

 <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </membership>

  <profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
  </providers>
  </profile>

 <roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
  </roleManager>

   </system.web>

   <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
      openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
      allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
      </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
      <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:32560/Service1.svc" binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </client>
      </system.serviceModel>
      </configuration>
```

Question:

-Is there anything wrong in the code ?
-I am unable to make a WCF    service call ? Firebug says 400 bad request ?

Comment: url: "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetData", localhost spelling is wrong

Comment: Yeah I know I made it like that because stackoverflow was giving me warning !

Comment: What happends if you browse to your service [http://localhost:32560/Service1.svc](http://localhost:32560/Service1.svc)

Comment: As far as I remember basicHttpBinding is for SOAP. Shouldn't your binding element be child of a webHttpBinding element instead of a basicHttpBinding element ?

Comment: @Martin - With WCF client I am able to access !

Comment: @jbl - I tried with web as well but, its still the same !

Comment: You should try with the most simple definition for your binding (trying to enable webget could also be a good option for testing with a browser) 
<webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>

Comment: You are trying to perform a POST operation from JQuery which does not generate the request message body according to SOAP standard (as you are using a BasicHttpBinding) rather change the binding to webHttpBinding which is REST and should be able to communicate with your service

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are able to browse the service in IIS. 
You web.config is missing `<services>` node it seems. Also there are some weird things:

Your binding is webHttpBinding but binding configuration is of basicHttpBinding with message security with username/password.

```
binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
```

Also there is service behavior with name "BasicHttpBinding_IService1".

If you trying out WCF REST create a fresh solution and try again.